# Find and copy directories containing file type

Tags: files, find, directory, cp, recursive

I have a directory "Movies" containing subdirectories "Movie Name". Each subdirectory "Movie Name" contains a movie file and related image/nfo files etc.

I'm trying to copy all directories containing movie file of type ".avi" to an external usb device.

So if `Directory/subdirectory A` contains `movie.avi`,  `poster.jpg` and `movie.nfo`, then I want to copy that directory and its contents to the external drive.

I've tried this:

```
find . -name "*.avi" -printf "%h\n" -exec cp {} /share/USBDisk1/Movies/ \;
```

But it only copies the file, not the directory and file contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, why your attempt doesn't work: `-printf "%h\n"` prints the directory part of the `.avi` file name. That doesn't affect anything in the subsequent `-exec` action — `{}` doesn't mean “whatever the last `printf` command printed”, it means “the path to the found file”.

If you want to use the directory part of the file name in that `cp` command, you need to modify the file name before passing it to `cp`. The `find` command doesn't have this capability, but a shell does, so make `find` invoke a shell which invokes `cp`.

```
find . -name "*.avi" -exec sh -c 'cp -Rp "${0%/*}" /share/USBDisk1/Movies/' {} \;
```

Note that you'll need to pass `-r` to `cp` since you're copying a directory. You should probably preserve metadata such as the files' modification time, too, with `-p`.

You may usefully replace `cp -Rp` by `rsync -a`. That way, if you've already copied a movie directory, it won't be copied again (unless its contents have changed).

Your command has a defect that may or may not affect you: if a directory contains multiple `.avi` files, it will be copied multiple times. It would be better to look for directories, and copy them if they contain a `.avi` file, rather than look for `.avi` files. If you use `rsync` instead of `cp`, the files won't be copied again, it's just a bit more work for `rsync` to verify the existence of the files over and over.

If all the movie directories are immediately under the toplevel directory, you don't need `find`, a simple loop over a wildcard pattern suffices.

```
for d in ./*/; do
  set -- "$d/"*.avi
  if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    # there is at least one .avi file in $d
    cp -rp -- "$d" /share/USBDisk1/Movies/
  fi
done
```

If the movie directories may be nested (e.g. `Movies/science fiction/Ridley Scott/Blade Runner`), you don't need `find`, a simple loop over a wildcard pattern suffices. You do need to be running ksh93 or bash ≥4 or zsh, and in ksh93 you need to run `set -o globstar` first, and in bash you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first. The wildcard pattern `**/` matches the current directory and all its subdirectories recursively (bash also traverses symbolic links to subdirectories).

```
for d in ./**/; do
  set -- "$d/"*.avi
  if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    cp -rp -- "$d" /share/USBDisk1/Movies/
  fi
done
```

Comment: The last one may copy a directory several times if its parent directory also contains `avi` files.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Going by the problem statement, the movie directories are direct subdirectories of the root anyway. If they aren't, then `movie1/1.avi` and `movie1/movie2/2.avi` should result in both `movie1/1.avi` and `movie2.2.avi` on the USB stick. I suppose the right thing to do would be to either not copy `movie1`'s subdirectories, or arrange to create hard links or symlinks (except that that's unlikely to work as the share is probably FAT).

Comment: This: `find . -name "*.avi" -exec sh -c 'cp -Rp "${0%/*}" /share/USBDisk1/Movies/' {} \;` is working a treat! It's a simple one time offload of files so this is the one for me. Thank you so much for your help. I don't think I would have ever gotten there!

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using GNU tools, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -printf '%h\0' |
  tr '\1/' '/\1' |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
  tr '\1/' '/\1' |
  awk -vRS='\0' -vORS='\0' '
    NR>1 && substr($0, 1, length(l)) == l {next}
    {print; l=$0"/"}' |
  xargs -r0 cp -rt /share/USBDisk1/Movies/
```

The above is GNU specific:

- for `find` (because of `-printf`)
- for `sort` because of `-z`
- for `awk` for the ability to handle NUL characters
- for `xargs` (for the `-r` and `-0` options, though some BSDs support them as well)
- `cp` (for `-t`)

The idea is:

- `find` outputs the dirnames of all the `avi` files.
- we sort that list so that every directory is listed after its parent directory (for that we need the `/` character to sort before any other one which is why we swap it with `\1`).
- we use `sort -u` so that each directory appears only once
- we use a small `awk` script to remove every directory entry for which an ancestor has already been included (as we don't want to copy both `./a` and `./a/b` if both contain AVI files).
- pass that list to `xargs`'s stdin so it can pass it as arguments to `cp -t target`.

Note that it doesn't try to protect against potential clashes if some directories after the same name.

If you want to reproduce the directory structure on the target drive, you can replace `xargs -r0 cp -rt /share/USBDisk1/Movies/` with

```
pax -0rw /share/USBDisk1/Movies/
```

(with a `pax` supporting the `-0` option such as the one found on Debian or MirBSD at least).

Ideally, you'd like to be able to write it like:

```
find . -type d -has '*.avi' -prune -exec cp -rt /target {} +
```

Unfortunately, `find` has no such `-has` predicate. The closest you can achieve would be:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c '
  shopt -s nullglob dotglob
  set -- "$1"/*.avi
  (( $# > 0 ))' sh {} \; \
  -prune -exec cp -r {} /share/USBDisk1/Movies/ \;
```

But that means calling one `bash` and redo the file listing within `bash` for each directory, so would probably be less efficient than the previous solution.

Comment: `find . -depth` does the sequencing you need

Comment: @jhill, `find -depth | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | tac | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'`, you mean? Even then, you'd still need to `sort` for `uniq` or make the `awk` part more complex, so that would hardly help

Comment: Why do the reversal?  -depth lists directories after their contents.

Comment: @jhill. yes and we need them before their content. Because if both `a` and `a/b` contain avi files, we want to copy `a` and not `a/b` (since we've already copied `a/b` as part of the `a` copy).

Comment: need a `-type f` on the find I think

Answer (score 1):

I found this one which I think is much simpler and pretty much results to what you need:

```
find . -name "*.avi" -exec cp "{}" /share/USBDisk1/Movies/ \;
```

I think similar way you did but without the `-printf` as the `"{}"` captures the output from find.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898462/moving-files-from-directory-and-all-subdirectories

Best,

Answer (score 0):

```
foo () 
{ 
    local subdirs=() target="$1" dest="$2";
    while IFS= read -rd ''; do
        subdirs+=("$REPLY");
    done < <(find "$target" -type f -iname '*.avi' -exec bash -c 'printf "%s\0" "${@%/*}"' _ {} + | sort -zu);
    cp -rp -- "${subdirs[@]}" "$dest"
}
```

**Usage:** `foo <source directory> <destination directory>`

Which will also address the following issue, mentioned previously by Gilles:

> Your command has a defect that may or may not affect you: if a
>   directory contains multiple .avi files, it will be copied multiple
>   times. It would be better to look for directories, and copy them if
>   they contain a .avi file, rather than look for .avi files.

Comment: Note that `-exec cmd ... {} +` does not guarantee that `cmd` be called only once. You'd better do the `sort -u` on the output of find and use `-printf '%h\n'` to take the dirname (since you're using a GNUism already) which would save executing bash. It should also be noted that your code is `bash` specific (though it takes little to change for it to also work in ksh93 or zsh), assumes the file names don't contain newline characters and may copy a directory more than once if a directory and its parent both happen to contain AVI files.

Comment: This will break on paths containing newlines.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `xargs` and `cp` to make the work:

`find . -name "*.avi" -printf "%h\n" | xargs cp -t /share/USBDisk1/Movies/ -r`

Comment: If the movie consists of multiple `.avi` files (that e.g. each would fit on a CD) than this results in multiple copies of the each all files for that movie. To USB that is slow.

Comment: The indicated that the subdirectories have spaces in them, so this will confuse `xargs`