# How to Copy Only the Directories with a specific File in that directory

Tags: rsync

```
Main_Directory
     |
Event_Subdirectories
     |
*.mcp .otherfiles
```

I want to copy all Event_Subdirectories to another Main_Directory that have the *.mcp file within the Event_subdirectory, but I'm unsure how to do that.  Do I use rsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### rsync

With rsync it should be fairly easy to do, though not complete.

Assuming `./new_Main_Directory` exists, otherwise `mkdir ./new_Main_Directory`

```
rsync -a --include '*/' --include '*.mcp' --exclude '*' Main_Directory/ new_Main_Directory/
```

This would copy only the *.mcp files and the directory structure they lie in.
You can always test `rsync` commands with the `--dry-run` option.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=763833

### cp

If you want to use cp, you can try something like the following.

```
for d in ./*/; do
set -- "$d/"*.mcp
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
   # there is at least one .mcp file in $d
   cp -rp -- "$d" ./new_Main_Directory/
fi
done
```

Source: [Find and copy directories containing file type](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75605/find-and-copy-directories-containing-file-type)

Answer (score 0):

The rsync command didn't really work, but the little for loop script worked perfectly.  It copied some other random files, but those were deleted.