# How to delete subfolders having only files of a specific extension

Tags: bash, shell-script, rm

I want to delete subfolders, only if all its files are of some specific extension, say json. I have seen a similar question [Find and copy directories containing file type](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75605/find-and-copy-directories-containing-file-type?rq=1). Thanks in advance.

```
├── 20101018_DSC05369.JPG
├── f
│   └── some.jpg
├── f1
│   ├── f
│   │   └── some.json
│   ├── f4
│   │   ├── a.jpg
│   │   └── some.json
│   └── some.json
└── some.jpg


exp. result:
.
├── 20101018_DSC05369.JPG
├── f
│   └── some.jpg
├── f1
│   ├── f4
│   │   ├── a.jpg
│   │   └── some.json
│   └── some.json
└── some.jpg
```

Comment: What should happen if a given directory is elegible for deletion but has one or more subdirectories that not meet the requirement for deletion?

Comment: it should not be deleted Paulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash
# recursively
shopt -s globstar || exit
# for every subfolder
for dir in **;do
      [[ ! -d $dir ]] && continue # if not directory then skip
      # SUBFOLDER name inspected
      echo "$dir"
      # count number of files in subfolder 
      NUMFILES=$(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l)
      # if non-empty folder
      if (( $(bc <<<"$NUMFILES > 0") )); then
      # if all files in folder have extension json, remove subfolder
              NUMJSON=$(find "$PWD/$dir" -iname '*.json' | wc -l)

              if (( $(bc <<<"$NUMFILES == $NUMJSON") )); then
                echo "rm -rf "$dir"" 
                rm -rf "$dir"
              fi
      fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one liner will solve your problem:

```bsh
sudo find . -links 2 -exec sh -c '[ "$(ls -l \{} | grep -c '^-')" \
-eq "$(ls \{} | grep -c '\.json$')" ]' \; -print0 | xargs -0  echo rm -rf {} + 2> /dev/null \;
```

Explanation of the code:

```bsh
sudo find . -links 2
```

In the current directory will only return leaf directories.

```bsh
 ls -l \{} | grep -c '^-'
```

returns the number of regular files in the directory.

```bsh
 ls \{} | grep -c '\.json$'
```

returns the number of files with `json` extension in the directory.

```bsh
sh -c '[ "$(ls -l \{} | grep -c '^-')" -eq "$(ls \{} | grep -c '\.json$')" ]'
```

spwans a sub-shell that returns true if all files in the directry have `json` extension, thus allowing the instruction to proceed.

```bsh
rm -rf {} + 2> /dev/null
```

will delete the non-empty directory redirecting standard error to /dev/null.

Caveat: This solution will delete found folders that do not contain any regular file.

Please backup your data before executing tests.

Execute the code in the top directory.

Remove echo when your tests succeed.

Comment: @Ferroao Please add the output from the comentary into the question to make it more readable.

Comment: @Ferroao Check corrections performed.

Comment: didnt work for me. seems this is not working sudo find . -links 2

Comment: What does `sudo find . -links 2` returns?

Comment: nothing ..  just nothing